# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem in form submition

Tags: jsf, classcastexception, selectonemenu

i have a form that contains a p:fileUpload. uploaded items are shown id p:dataGrid and i can remove them.
when i upload some files and submit form, there is no problem. but when i upload files and remove some of them and then submit form, i get this exception:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to       javax.faces.model.SelectItem
 at javax.faces.component.SelectItemsIterator.initializeItems(SelectItemsIterator.java:185)
 at javax.faces.component.SelectItemsIterator.hasNext(SelectItemsIterator.java:131)
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

my xhtml file is as below:

```
  <h:panelGrid style="margin: 0 auto; width:65%; margin-top: 60px;">
        <p:panel header="#{msg['create.job']}">
            <h:form id="createJobForm">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['job.type']}" for="jobType"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{createJobBean.jobWrapper.type}" placeholder="#{msg['job.type']}"
                                     id="jobType">
                        <f:selectItem value="#{createJobBean.jobWrapper.type}"
                                      itemLabel="#{createJobBean.type1.value}"
                                      itemValue="#{createJobBean.type1}"/>
                        <f:selectItem value="#{createJobBean.jobWrapper.type}"
                                      itemLabel="#{createJobBean.type2.value}"
                                      itemValue="#{createJobBean.type2}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['title']}" for="title"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{createJobBean.jobWrapper.title}" id="title" style="width:717px;"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['content']}" for="content"/>
                    <p:inputTextarea id="content" value="#{createJobBean.jobWrapper.content}" cols="100"
                                     style="width:717px;"/>
                    <p:outputLabel/>
                    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{createJobBean.fileUpload}" mode="advanced"
                                  dragDropSupport="false"
                                  style="width: 727px;" multiple="true" sizeLimit="500000" fileLimit="10"
                                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|docx|pdf)$/" update="attachPanel"/>
                    <p:outputLabel/>
                    <p:dataGrid id="attachPanel" style="margin-top: 20px;" columns="1"
                                value="#{createJobBean.attachments}" var="attach">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-closethick"
                                         style="width: 20px;height: 20px; margin-left: 10px; background:orange">
                            <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{createJobBean.removeAttachment(attach)}"
                                    update=":createJobForm"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{attach}" style="color: blue;"/>
                    </p:dataGrid>
                    <p:outputLabel/>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['save']}"
                                     actionListener="#{createJobBean.addJob}"
                                     update=" createJobForm" style="margin-top: 20px;" icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:panel>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

if i remove some file form attachPanel and then click save button i get that exception.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to upload multiple files at the same time?

Comment: yes , i choose multiple time at the same time. but when i did not remove any file from dataGrid, there is no problem

Comment: Please provide also the relevant part of `createJobBean` - at least the method `removeAttachment` could be helpful. Also, in PrimeFaces all command buttons use Ajax by default, so the actions behind the `p:ajax` element should be possible to move directly to the `p:commandButton`

Comment: ok. i fix problem with removing value attribute in f:selectItem. i am wonder why without removing attachments from attachPanel , i did not have any problem!